# Symmetry on a sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, surfaces

Let $u$ be a smooth function on the sphere $S^2$. Suppose there exists $C>0$ such that for all $R \in SO(3)$, the area of every connected component of $\{x\in S^2: u(x)> u(Rx)\}$ is at least $C$. Is $u$ a constant function?  ($u(Rx)$ is a rotation of $u$ on $S^2$)

Comment: How do you get nonempry components for the constant function?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: If $u$ is constant, then for any $R$, $\{x\in S^2:u(x)>u(Rx) \} = \emptyset$, so all of its connected components (all 0 of them) have area $> C$. I don't see a problem here :-)

Comment: OK, this is an interesting way to interpret the area of the empty set, but let it be :)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Edgar's comment was not about the area of the empty set.  It was about the area of every one of the components, and the empty set is not a component.  Since there are no components when $u$ is constant, what he wrote about all their areas is vacuously true.

Comment: Yes, I got it. The ":)" was supposed to explain that.

Comment: I revised the question. Now the statement is "... area of every nonempty connected component...". I hope this settles the issue Alex was concerned about:)

Comment: As Edgar and Andreas pointed out, and Alex agreed, the revision was not needed and it does not change anything. By the way, there is no such thing as an empty connected component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. One may consider the function $u(x,y,z)=x$ on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. If $R(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)$ then your set is empty, otherwise it is an open hemisphere.

One may replace $u=x$ by any strictly monotonous function in $x$.

Comment: Thanks Ilya. The example you provided is axially symmetric. Do you think the above property can imply some sort of symmetry result on u?