# Symmetry on a sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

Let $u$ be a smooth function on the sphere $S^2$. Suppose there exists $C>0$ such that for all $R \in SO(3)$, the area of every nonempty connected component of $\{x\in S^2: u(x)> u(Rx)\}$ is at least $C$ ($u(Rx)$ is a rotation of $u$ on $S^2$). Such function can't be "too" non-symmetric. I wonder what kind of symmetry results the above condition implies.

If $u$ is a monotone axially symmetric function, then nonempty components of $\{x\in S^2: u(x)> u(Rx)\}$ are open hemispheres. So axially symmetric functions can satisfy the condition. Does the above condition necessarily imply that $u$ is axially symmetric? If not, can we deduce a weaker notion of symmetry?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before.  Does it appear somewhere else?

Comment: The prequel to this question, bearing the same title, is here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161600/symmetry-on-a-sphere

Comment: Thanks Yoav.  For the OP, could you let us know what you mean by a "symmetry results", and perhaps why you're interested in this question?   Some context would maybe get people motivated.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade: substantiation for removal [real-analysis] [spherical-geometry] [symmetry] [orthogonal-groups]? 

Is here a damn Wikipedia to rollback good-faith edits indiscriminately? [curves-and-surfaces] [surfaces] obviously havn’t any specificity with respect to this problem.

Comment: Dear @Incnis Mrsi, perhaps my roll-back was not the best course of action. This question is hard to tag by nature, and the current tags are not that good. Nevertheless, I think this question is not quite about real analysis, and it certainly is not about spherical geometry, even if it involves spheres and some sort of geometry. Moreover, I am not very fond of the tag 'symmetry', which is often improperly used as a meta-tag of sorts. In that light, I decided to simply roll-back your change to this month-old question. (to be continued...)

Comment: (continuation) I do agree that, despite its problems, the tag 'symmetry' could be appropriate here. The tag 'orthogonal-groups' is also OK. Please feel free to re-edit this question if you like. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Different types of symmetry are discussed explicitly, hence [symmetry]. SO(3) is referred from the formulation, hence [orthogonal-groups]. It is the motion group of spherical geometry, hence [spherical-geometry]. The function *u* is real and smooth, hence [real-analysis].

What does [curves-and-surfaces] mean at all? If we understand **and** as a logical connective, then where is any curve? Why [surfaces] for uniform positive-curvature “plane”, but not so for uniform zero-curvature plane (ℝ²)? Waiting for a third-party opinion.

Comment: Dear @Incnis Mrsi, I think you are unlikely to get a third opinion on this question, unless its author stops by: it has long left the front page, and most people don't explicitly care very much about tags. The current tags are what they are because the original post was tagged 'dg.differential-geometry', 'geometry', 'curves-and-surfaces, 'surfaces', 'elliptic-surfaces'. Afterwards, I simply removed the deprecated tag 'geometry' and the inappropriate tag 'elliptic-surfaces'. I left the rest unchanged because the question was hard to tag and I did not know what the original poster had in mind.

Comment: As I said above, if you feel strongly about this question, please feel free to retag it. Again, I apologize for the inconvenience.